# minimizing occurrence of gaps during sequence generation

Tags: oracle11g

I know that sequence does not guarantee absence of gaps, but I want to minimize their occurrence, so they will occur only in exceptional situations (preferably only when transaction rolls back).

I have several nodes in RAC which may concurrently access sequence.

```
create sequence seq_1 start with 1 order; # this seems to return numbers without gaps, but what will happen when database is restarted? will cached elements be dropped?
create sequence seq_2 start with 1 nocache; # this one also seems to return numbers in order without gaps, but I heard some objections about using nocache as it hinders performance
create sequence seq_3 start with 1 nocache order; # any improvements over previous two?
```

So which one is better?

As an alternative I could use a table for storing sequence number, but currently I want to consider sequence based solution rather than table based.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For your 1st statement, if the DB is restarted, NOCACHE is not specified so it would default to 20, so for sure you will loose numbers. But there is no point in worrying about losing the numbers, since rollback, shutdown will definitely "lose" a number (As you rightly said).

**ASKTOM Quote:** "If you have CACHE = NOCACHE, you will of course not "lose" any, you don't have any cached to lose. If you pin a cached sequence, you'll lose some on shutdown but not otherwise. SEQUENCES are not gap free under ANY circumstance -- EVER.  They are 100% assured to have a gap at 
some point.  100%"

Using ORDER is only to guarantee ordered generation for RAC. If you are using exclusive mode, then sequence numbers are always generated in order. Since NOORDER is the default, go for ORDER keyword.

If you omit both CACHE and NOCACHE, then the database caches 20 sequence numbers by default. Oracle recommends using the CACHE setting to enhance performance if you are using sequences in an Oracle Real Application Clusters environment.

Go for NOCYLCE if you want to manage it your way.

Using the CACHE and NOORDER options together results in the best performance for a sequence. 
CACHE option is used without the ORDER option, each instance caches a separate range of numbers and sequence numbers may be assigned out of order by the different instances.

CACHE option causes each instance to cache its own range of numbers, thus reducing I/O to the Oracle Data Dictionary, and the NOORDER option eliminates message traffic over the interconnect to coordinate the sequential allocation of numbers across all instances of the database. 
NOCACHE will be SLOW...

Read [this](http://www.pythian.com/blog/sequences-in-oracle-10g-rac/)

My suggestion would be a temp table to hold the SEQNAME, STARTVAL, ENDVAL, CURRVAL as columns and use them as CURRVAL+1 and update the latest. -- For strict numbering and can have better control, but reinventing the wheel.

If you still need to stick with sequences, then my suggestion would be NOCACHE, ORDER, NOCYCLE.

Comment: this is the opposite to what I want to achieve. Every node in RAC will cache 20 elements, so there will be something like this 1, 20, 2, 21 when sequence is accessed from different nodes.

Comment: Sorry never noticed Real Application Cluster. I will repost.

Comment: What advantage is there to building your own vs using a sequence object with NOCACHE, ORDER, NOCYCLE?

Comment: ORDER is not a must for RAC, only in cases where you want sequences to be given out in a certain order. Even then, if your complex code first retrieves `sequence.NEXTVAL` and then does a long sequence of processing before inserting a record, chances are that another transaction will insert earlier. For proper ordering of records, I always recommend the use of `systimestamp` above the use of sequences.

Comment: I agree on ORDER. Will correct it. About the advantage, as i said, no loosing numbers for Option1 with better control. Option 2, using inbuilt sequences and leave the rest to Oracle.